Existence of composite function with algebraic and exponential functions
We are supposed to test the validity of two statements:
(1) There exists a differentiable function $g:R\rightarrow R$ such that $g(x^3+x^5)=e^x-100$
(2) There exists a continuous function $g:R\rightarrow R$ such that $g(e^x)=x^3+x^5$
Problem is from ISI B STAT 2024 examination
I think both of them are false. In the first function if we differentiate g'(0) is not defined and in the second function g(x) is not define for $R^-$. Please verify the answer and suggest a mathematical way to approach the problem.

In case $(2)$ the condition determines the values of $g$ on $\mathbb{R}_+.$ It does not mean that the values of $g$ for $x\le 0$ are undefined. For instance $g(x)=0$ when $x\le 0.$ The problem is whether we can extend the function defined for $x>0$ to a continuous function on the real line.

@RyszardSzwarc Thank you for the answer. Can you please explicitly  say which statement is correct or incorrect

Concerning $(2),$ the function $g$ satisfies $$g(t)=(\log t)^3+(\log t)^5\quad t>0$$ Hence $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to 0^+}g(t)=-\infty.$
Therefore $g$ cannot be continuous at $0.$
For $(1)$ the chain rule gives $$(3x^2+5x^4)g'(x^3+x^5)=e^x$$ Plugging in $x=0$ leads to a contradiction.
Summarizing, both statements are false.
Remark Let's generalize the first question to $$g(x^3+x^5)=f(x)$$ where $f$ is differentiable. Assume the solution exists. Let $h(x)$ denote the function inverse to $x^3+x^5.$ Then $g(t)=f(h(t))$ satisfies the identity. Morevoer $g$ is differentiable for $t\neq 0,$ as $h(t)$ is differentiable for $t\neq 0.$ At $0$ we have $$\lim_{t\to 0}{g(t)-g(0)\over t}=\lim_{t\to 0}{f(h(t))-f(h(0))\over t}=\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)-f(0)\over x^3+x^5}$$ So the function $g$ is differentiable at $0$ iff the last limit exists. If the limit exists then $f'(0)=0.$ For example $f(x)=x\sin^2$ is fine unlike $f(x)=\sin^2x.$

@Ryszard-szwarc Does that mean statement 1 is true and statement 2 is false?

Both are false. The remark analyzes a more general case of $(1)$ where the right hand side has been replaced by a general differentiable function $f$ in place of $e^x-100.$ The answer is positive if $f$ satisfies a condition which implies $f'(0)=0.$ Your function does not satisfy this condition, as $f'(0)\neq 0.$

Understood now, Thank you.
